# How to create User/Database for Docker Postgres and connect from host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to setup Postgres in Docker container for development. There is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM postgres:10.2
ADD ./init-test-db.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-test-db.sql
ADD ./postgresql.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
ADD ./pg_hba.conf /tmp/pg_hba.conf
ADD ./copy-conf.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/copy-conf.sh
EXPOSE 5432
```

I use **init-test-db.sql** to create DB user and database:

```
CREATE USER testUser WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'testUserPsw';
CREATE DATABASE testdb;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testUser;
```

I use my own **postgresql.conf** version to ensure that **listen_addresses = '*'** is set. **copy-conf.sh** is used to copy my **pg_hba.conf** version to Postgres inside container:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp /tmp/pg_hba.conf /var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

My **pg_hba.conf** adds one line to default configuration:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Command to build my docker image:

```
docker build -t postgres-test .
```

Command to run container:

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name testpg -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgrespsw postgres-test
```

I want to be able to login to Postgres inside Docker container with testUser from my local machine. I see the error message in Postgres container when I try to do it:

```
[72] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testUser"
[72] DETAIL:  Role "testUser" does not exist.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 83: "host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5"
```

I'm able to connect using **postgres** superuser. So it seems that Postgres is accessible. There is something wrong with **testUser**.

I've tried this SQL statement:

```
SELECT u.usename AS "User name",
       u.usesysid AS "User ID",
       CASE WHEN u.usesuper AND u.usecreatedb THEN CAST('superuser, create database' AS pg_catalog.text)
       WHEN u.usesuper THEN CAST('superuser' AS pg_catalog.text)
       WHEN u.usecreatedb THEN CAST('create database' AS
                                    pg_catalog.text)
       ELSE CAST('' AS pg_catalog.text)
       END AS "Attributes"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user u
ORDER BY 1;
```

It shows that testUser is there. Maybe someone has any idea what's wrong with my setup?